# Unable to find dimens value usage in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout

I use Android Studio for development(professionally). 
If i have to find something in a project , I usually search for the usages in strings.xml and dimens.xml 
Sometimes, since the same dimens resource value is used in different files, I find the usages and check the files it is being used in.
But I've noticed a strange thing and its been worrying me frequently.
If I try to find the usages of a certain dimens value being used multiple places in the project. I get the following error.

> Cannot search for usages.
>   Position to an element to find usages for, and try again.

Screenshot of error: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiNXu.png)

And the worst part is it happens intermittently.
Any idea how to fix this. :
PS: I use Android Studio: 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same thing too, and I ended up getting a solution for that. If you are on Windows, use ctl+shift+F (or Mac, cmd+shift+F), then Android Atudio will pop a find-in-path window with many options.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. May i know what keymap are you using for cmd_shift+F.

Comment: what d u mean cmd+shift+F didn't work ? the find in path window doesn't open or the search it self does't return any thing ?